# What is this manga with a female protagonist that changes genders and personalities based on the rings she wears?

Tags: phd-phantasy-degree

I have been searching for a while now (about a month) and I am trying to find a manga that has a female protagonist who changes gender and appearance based on how many rings of power she is wearing. Her personality also changes depending on the amount of rings.

She is a wizard and the manga starts in a devil school in which she is trying to obtain another ring.

Comment: Sounds like [PhD: Phantasy Degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhD:_Phantasy_Degree).

Comment: @Krazer might want to post it as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@Krazer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/63/krazer) pointed out, your description matches that of the Korean manhwa series [*PhD: Phantasy Degree*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhD:_Phantasy_Degree), wherein the female protagonist changes genders each time a ring is removed from her finger, as well as each ring having its own "personality."

From the link above:

> A young, spunky, fearless girl named Sang is searching for the Demon School Hades. She runs into a group of misfit monsters who are all ditching classes from the same school. Sang convinces them to take her to the school ... and, since only monsters are allowed in, she 'monsterizes' herself by letting one of the misfits - a vampire - bite her. After the destruction of the Demon School Hades at the hands of the Madosa Guild in volume 3, she moves on to search for more of "Satan's Rings". She meets Chun-Lang, a young swordsman, who also has a Ring, and like Sang, can change genders.

[image: Cover of PhD: Phantasy Degree]

Comment: Oh weird. Could have sworn I edited the description to say it was answered since I'm new and cant do it myself. :P

Comment: @Sara Because of the format of the site, we prefer if answers are separate from the questions. :)

Comment: Sorry, being new as I am it wouldn't let me post the answer as an answer. It stated to post it in the question or something because I'm to new to answer my own question. :/ it was weird. So my post was un-updated then? w.e it works :)